# MOXy XMLCompositeCollectionMapping descriptor is missing

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy, docx4j

docx4j (which I host) is typically used with the Sun/Oracle JAXB implementation; the classes of interest below were generated using XJC.

I thought I'd try EclipseLink MOXy, to see how it went.

On context init, I get the following error:

```
ERROR org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 107 - Cannot initialize context
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-110] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Descriptor is missing for class [org.docx4j.vml.spreadsheetDrawing.STCF].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[moveWithCellsOrSizeWithCellsOrAnchor]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.docx4j.vml.spreadsheetDrawing.CTClientData --> [DatabaseTable(ns15:ClientData)])

Exception [EclipseLink-110] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Descriptor is missing for class [org.docx4j.bibliography.STSourceType].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[abbreviatedCaseNumberOrAlbumTitleOrAuthor]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.docx4j.bibliography.CTSourceType --> [])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-110] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Descriptor is missing for class [org.docx4j.vml.spreadsheetDrawing.STCF].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[moveWithCellsOrSizeWithCellsOrAnchor]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.docx4j.vml.spreadsheetDrawing.CTClientData --> [DatabaseTable(ns15:ClientData)])

Exception [EclipseLink-110] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Descriptor is missing for class [org.docx4j.bibliography.STSourceType].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[abbreviatedCaseNumberOrAlbumTitleOrAuthor]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.docx4j.bibliography.CTSourceType --> [])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:79)
    at org.docx4j.samples.OpenMainDocumentAndTraverse.<clinit>(OpenMainDocumentAndTraverse.java:52)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-110] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Descriptor is missing for class [org.docx4j.vml.spreadsheetDrawing.STCF].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[moveWithCellsOrSizeWithCellsOrAnchor]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.docx4j.vml.spreadsheetDrawing.CTClientData --> [DatabaseTable(ns15:ClientData)])

Exception [EclipseLink-110] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Descriptor is missing for class [org.docx4j.bibliography.STSourceType].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[abbreviatedCaseNumberOrAlbumTitleOrAuthor]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.docx4j.bibliography.CTSourceType --> [])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.<init>(XMLContext.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.<init>(XMLContext.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.<init>(XMLContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$ContextPathInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:696)
    ... 13 more
```

The first pair of referenced classes, we have an enum [STCF](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/vml/spreadsheetDrawing/STCF.java) and [CTClientData](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/vml/spreadsheetDrawing/CTClientData.java)

The second pair of referenced classes, we have another enum [STSourceType](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/bibliography/STSourceType.java) and [CTSourceType](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/bibliography/CTSourceType.java)

How might I workaround this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I have been able to recreate the issue you are seeing.  The issue you are seeing is due to the following bug:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/380122

**UPDATE**

This issue has now been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.3.3 and 2.4.0 streams.  You can download a nightly build that contains the fix from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Comment: Thank you very much Blaise for taking the time to look at this issue.

Comment: @JasonPlutext - This issue has now been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.3.3 and 2.4.0 streams.  You can download a nightly build with the fix from the following location:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php